# How can i check if character occurs twice

Tags: regex, scala

I want to check if any character occurs exactly 2 times and if any character occurse exactly 3 times. Somehow i can't get it to work.

```
  val pattern1 = "(.)\\1{1}"
  val pattern2 = "(.)\\1{2}"
  private def checkLine(line: String): (Int, Int) = {
    if(line.matches(pattern1) && line.matches(pattern2)) (1, 1)
    else if(line.matches(pattern2)) (0, 1)
    else if(line.matches(pattern1)) (1, 0)
    else (0, 0)
  }
```

It returns always (0, 0)

Comment: `matches` requires a full string match.

Comment: You want in continuation or can appear anywhere in string?

Comment: anywhere in string.
For example abcda should return (1, 0)
abcdaa (0, 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the two regexes that only matches if there is at least a character that is occurring exactly only twice,

```
^(?=.*(.).*\1)(?!(.*\1){3}).*$
```

[Demo for exactly 2 char repeating](https://regex101.com/r/6e1im1/1)

And this one for a character exactly exactly repeating thrice.

```
^(?=.*(.)(?:.*\1){2})(?!(.*\1){4}).*$
```

[Demo for exactly 3 characters repeating](https://regex101.com/r/RFRMM5/1)

Answer (score 0):

I made you a different solution for you that won't use regex:

```
val str: String = "Hello World!"

// Split the String into Strings containing single chars
val arr: Array[String] = str.split("")

// Group the characters into Arrays
val grouped: Array[Array[String]] = arr.groupBy[String](identity[String])
  .values
  .toArray

// Extract the count of the inner Array
val counted: Array[Int] = grouped.map(_.size)

// Create a tuple containing the information if 2 or 3 values have been found
val tuple: (Boolean, Boolean) = (counted.contains(2), counted.contains(3))

// Transform it into the required representation (true => 1, false => 0)
val tuple2: (Int, Int) = (if(tuple._1) 1 else 1, if(tuple._2) 1 else 0)

println(tuple2)
```

Result:

```
(1, 1)
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/7l4813x/1)

---

Some information what `arr.groupBy[String](identity[String])` does:

`groupBy` allows for a transformation prior to grouping. Most of the times this is necessary, but not in this case. Here we want to group together Strings that are equal. As we don't want to transform the values, we instead use `identity[T]` (which is a more beautiful way of writing `a => a`).

---

I hope this helps.